# Adding Line Numbers To Pre-formatted Text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a body of text that I show in a web page within some `<pre>` tags. I would like to add a column to the left of this text body to show the line number of the text.

The body of text is retrieved by using [PHP] `file_get_contents()` so I am just `echo`-ing a string within the `<pre>` tags.

I imagine this can be accomplished with JavaScript but I have yet to find a solution.

Solutions I have seen on here usually use a library or CSS. The CSS method would be great but this method seems to require that each line of the body text have its own corresponding tag (eg `<p>` or `<span>`).

```
// Example of CSS Solution

p:not(:first-child):before {
  counter-increment: custom-counter+1;
  content: counter(custom-counter)". ";
  display: table-cell;
}
p:first-child:before {
  display: table-cell;
  content: '1. '
}
```

I would like to avoid having to create a DOM element (before load) line by line. That said, if that is the best solution I simply want to know the "preferred" way to go about this.

How could I accomplish this using JavaScript / jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution would be to split the string on "\n" with javascript to get each line append the line numbers then re-join them together. This will only work if you are using `<pre>` tags where newlines are literal newlines.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uqbj4waz/)

```
    let text = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;
    let lines = text.split("\n");
    for (let i=0;i<lines.length;i++) {
        lines[i] = (i+1)+" "+lines[i];
    }
    text = lines.join("\n");
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = text;
```